# How can I clean this cooking pan?

Tags: cleaning, pan

I have this non-stick tefal cooking pan which works great - nothing sticks to the telfon part.

The only problem is the silver metal rim to the pan - it just gets more and more brown the more often I use it. It requires more scrubbing with soap than I am able to manage if I want it to stay shiny silver. How can I clean the brown gunk off?

[image: picture of cooking pan]

Comment: use a 3m scrubbing pad.

Comment: What's the actual material of the pan? I doubt it's an actual silver finish after all

Comment: In my experience, a scrubbing pad will cost you hours of work without noticeable results, but you are welcome to try and prove me wrong if you want to. The material of this strip is usually stainless steel, and the way it glints is suggestive for it. The pan itself (below the teflon) is almost surely aluminium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't clean it.

You have the same issue as in [How to remove film from stainless steel pan](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/how-to-remove-film-from-stainless-steel-pan). This is polymerised oil, the same stuff which is intentionally built on cast iron pans. The cleaning methods listed in the linked question will also work in your case.

But the catch is that they will also strip the teflon from your pan. So, unless you are completely sure that you can somehow clean the steel part only, without getting drops of abrasives and strong chemicals on the teflon, don't bother. It doesn't harm anything, and it surely isn't contaminating your food with anything. And if you do try something caustic on the strip, don't use it on the rim, because the strip is probably SS, but the pan's bowl is likely to be aluminium and will be corroded by many aggressive cleaning products.