# How do I clean my hob?

Tags: cleaning, stove

I am using a Creda Capri hotplate hob (possibly [this one [pdf]](http://media.stars.manchester.ac.uk/files/accommodation/CREDA%20Capri%20C150E.pdf)).

The problem is the area around the burners has became too dirty, with sticky burns. Here's a photo:

[image: dirty stove]

I have tried using [Dettol Spray Power And Pure Kitchen](http://www.dettol.co.uk/power-and-pure.php) but was unable to remove the stains. What I can do?

Comment: It looks to me like polymerized oil ... soap, hot water, and one of those green scrubbing pads generally works for me.  The only problem is that if you scrub too much you might leave little scratches making this even harder to clean the next time around.  (you've basically done the same reaction as seasoning a cast iron pan ... so scratches will help it cling better).

Comment: @jefromi, thanks for editing. Given that this was my first post, I was unable to add more than 2 links.

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/how-to-remove-film-from-stainless-steel-pan   I think Barkeeper's Friend (oxalic acid is the active ingredient, if that product is not available where you live) may help with less risk of scratching your cooktop.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck using a finer grade [steel wool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_wool), though don't press too hard. For smaller stains I really like "[magic eraser](http://www.mrclean.com/en_US/magic-eraser.do)" type sponges which work wonders on the hood as well. I don't know what country you are posting from, but the magic erasers are like a very high density foam sponge. They are amazing on soap scum too.

Answer (score 1):

Pour vinegar on it leave for 5 mins. Then add table salt. Leave to soak and then gently rub it off. Repeat until it comes up clean. You can also use bicarbonate of soda with the salt if it does not come up clean.

Answer (score 0):

Applying neat washing up liquid or a paste-based cleaner like Astonish with a toothbrush might be less abrasive than using a scourer (even a nylon-based one) and should loosen or break up the deposits, which can then be gently rubbed away with a microfibre cloth.  I've found that, once the area is scratched, the burn marks soon reappear, but if you use a microfibre cloth after each use, it should help to minimise the build up.

Answer (score 0):

Try baking soda. Pour liberally over the burned area and cover with a damp cloth. Come back in an hour or so, and you should find that most of the mess wipes right off. I haven't tried it on this type of hob, but I have used it to great effect with food burnt onto a glass-top surface even when scrubbing was unsuccessful, as well as for stains on countertops.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck removing gummy oil like that using a degreaser like citrus oil or Greased Lightening. It still takes a lot of elbow grease, but a degreaser will help loosen it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Easy-Off" oven cleaner. Spray and leave it for couple of minutes and just wipe it off. This will really work out in removing your stains.

Try applying vinegar with hot water too.

[image]

Comment: Will this mar typical visible finishes like enamel or stainless steel?

Comment: Easy-Off is very harsh and contains nasty chemicals. Not one to use if you have children and pets around according to the guy who does our properties ovens over at <a href="http://www.ovencleaningsheffield.com">oven cleaning sheffield</a>

Answer (score 0):

Soda crystals - I note that Azula R has suggested baking soda, don't think that's quite the same thing, because household soda crystals aren't meant for cooking use. Switch the power off, make up a very strong, hot solution and pour into the hob so that it's as full as it can be without overflowing. Leave to soak for as long as possible,couple of hours at least, top up if it evaporates. It should mean (provided you can get the solution depth high enough) the solidified oil/grease just lifts off. Bit of a pain to remove because you can't lift the hob to pour it, but it can be done by sopping it up.