# How to avoid oil burn on the exterior of stainless steel pan

Tags: stainless-steel, searing

After I sear a steak the exterior sides and bottom of my stainless steel pan get coated with what looks like burned oil.

I usually let it cool down, then fill with the soapy water for overnight soaking. Only to find all the exterior stained in the morning.

I am puzzled how that happens: I’m using a splatter screen and while cooking the exterior does not seem dirty.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, how does filling the interior with soapy water relate to the exterior of your pan (which is likely coated with polymerized oil that was aerosolized during cooking)?

Comment: Just wanted to give a description of how I treat the pan after cooking. Don’t know if it’s important.

Comment: Highly related, possibly duplicates: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113929/why-do-my-stainless-steel-fry-pans-always-develop-a-residue?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/how-to-remove-film-from-stainless-steel-pan?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blackening on the exterior of your pan begins with the polymerization of oils, which sometimes spill over, but often times collect there as a result of being aerosolized while you are cooking.  This happens whether or not use use a splash screen.  To have any luck cleaning this, you have to get it right after cooking, and you have to work at it quite a bit with an abrasive cleaner. When it first appears, if you catch it before burning, it is usually brown. After a couple of uses (or high heat, long enough) it will blacken and be even more difficult to remove.  Some folks like a shiny exterior and will work at this diligently after each use.  Personally, I don't give the exterior of my pans much attention.  For the stainless ones, the inside is shiny and clean, the exterior is black and not so pretty to look at.  I don't find it impacts the functionality at all.

Answer (score 1):

Every so often I have a go at my pans' exteriors. [Mostly I don't bother but sometimes a bit of OCD kicks in]

Barkeeper's Friend, either a Brillo [steel wool pad] or if you don't want scratches several melamine sponges… plus two hours of scrubbing. Scraping at heavier bits with a fingernail helps.

Alternatively, for uncoated pans like stainless steel, a good oven cleaner, left to soak for four hours or so [don't let it dry out]. Periodically scrape or brush with your dish wash brush & re-apply.

Comment: Is carbon stainless steel any easier to maintain? Or any other kind, or even with glazed / coated exterior?

Comment: They're all as hard to keep clean - the hardest, though, are the ones whose surface can be damaged by harsh cleaners. The burnt-on matter is the same in all cases.