# What happened to my pot?

Tags: utensils, pot, safety

My pot has turned dark after my last usage as seen in the picture:[image]

What happened to the pot and if I continue cooking with it will the food become contaminated? The surface of the pot is still smooth and the stain does not go away when scrubbed.

Comment: Hey, your question already has an answer: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/120038/7180   In short, it's burned-on oil, it's harmless but very hard to remove.